# _dateData is null inside an awaited asynch Task

Tags: datetime, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1

I am stepping through a .NET Core 3.1 service and the code is blowing up with a null exception on the following line:

```
DateTime maxOwnerValidDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

The exception is:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

maxOwnerValidDate._dateData was null.
```

After researching _dateData, I found that this is something introduced by .NET 6, 7. I did recently update the environment on this machine to .NET 6. Interestingly, the above statement does not throw any exceptions if placed elsewhere in the code. It is only failing when the statement exists inside of an asynch Task.

At this point, I am not interested in upgrading this .NET Core project to .NET6/7 (yet). I'm just debugging something else.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? How can I get the code to continue to function here without rolling back the .NET6 install or working from another environment?

The inner workings of the new DateTime object and the new private ulong _dateData property and why it would be null inside a new DateTime object declared inside an asnych Task are so far beyond my skill set that I have nothing to lean on.

[VS break on exception screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii4Uk.png)

ADDITIONS:

I have found that it is in fact related to pushing through the code by manually moving the step pointer in Visual Studio. In some cases there is no impact. Here there is a very repeatable, very specific, very odd failure.

Sample code to recreate:

```
public async Task ProcessWorkflow(List<Object> steps)
{
    foreach (Object step in steps)
    {
        bool pushingForward = true; //<<< Breakpoint 1 here <<<
        DateTime maxOwnerValidDate = DateTime.UtcNow; //Manually push through to here and step forward (F10)
        bool success = await ProcessWorkflowSteps(step); //Success: maxOwnerValidDate populated, no exception thrown.
    }
}

public async Task<bool> ProcessWorkflowSteps(Object step)
{
    List<int> someStuff = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
    bool thisShouldRun = false;
    if (thisShouldRun)  //<<< Breakpoint 2 here <<<
    {                   //Manually push into if clause here and step forward (F10)
        DateTime maxOwnerValidDate = DateTime.UtcNow; // Step forward here (F10). Exception thrown here.
    // For some reason, if the next line is not present, the above statement succeeds without exception.
    List<int> Ids = someStuff.Where(stuff => maxOwnerValidDate <= DateTime.UtcNow).ToList();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `maxOwnerValidDate`(its struct) nor `_dateData`(its primitive) can be null. So you misinterpreting something. Btw `_dateData` field exists since NET Framework 2.0.

Based on updated info you skipping closure object initialization (it captures state for lambdas or `async` functions).

Here is decompiled code [sharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(5);
<someStuff>5__1 = list;
<thisShouldRun>5__2 = false;
if (!<thisShouldRun>5__2) //<<< Breakpoint 2 here <<<
{
    goto IL_0105;
}
<>8__3 = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0(); // <<< ! this skipped !
<>8__3.maxOwnerValidDate = DateTime.UtcNow;  // Step forward here (F10). Exception thrown here.
<Ids>5__4 = Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Where(<someStuff>5__1, new Func<int, bool>(<>8__3.<<Main>$>b__1)));
awaiter = Task.Delay(1000).GetAwaiter();
```

In your first example `maxOwnerValidDate` is not captured, so it's not promoted to closure.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. I'm sure I am not understanding something here. Also I did find that being inside a task has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JesselAquing make sure that source code matches actual code being run (there is option in VS to demand that). Also if you debugging Release build, source stepping doesn't work quite well so, probably this line is unrelated, see some code around for `null` values

Comment: @JesselAquing also I recommend to inspect Call Stack window and exception StackTrace

Comment: I verified those things as well as all the basic "VS is acting up" types of resolutions (restart, rebuild etc.) I found if I move the statement up a few lines (outside of a couple if clauses), it succeeds and I can see the variable has a value in the Watch. However, when the variable is evaluated in the subsequent lines, back inside the if clauses, VS throws another null exception. I have confirmed that it is definitely complaining about the maxOwnerValidDate being null even though I can see the date value is not null. It does not specify any internal private props being at fault, as before.

Comment: Seems like bug in debugger. Try to update Visual Studio and use corresponding Remote Debugger C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger (if it used)

Comment: Are you using any IL modifying tools like PostSharp or Fody ?

Comment: Does exception occurs if launched without debugger? (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: No IL tools. I'll try running it without the debugger, but for full transparency, the reason I was stepping through it was because I was trying to test a very specific, contrived, scenario and manually pushing the breakpoint through by skipping certain statements and clauses. So running it without the debugger now, it would not hit the same lines of code. I really hope that me manipulating the debugger position has nothing to do with this but it can't be ruled out.

Comment: It does makes sense. You updated SDK to Net 6 and using newer version of Roslyn which probably changed IL emit for closures, so by skipping some statements you somehow skipping closure initialization and null pointer is actually closure. `async` functions always produce closure for variables used between `await` statements.

Answer (score 0):

With normal execution, the code is hit and succeeds without error. However, manually manipulating the execution position causes the DateTime variable to fail to instantiate with an inexplicable exception.

> ._dateData was null.

When dragging the arrow, VS tries to warn you about this activity:

> This is the next statement that will be executed. To change which
> statement is executed next, drag the arrow. This may have unintended
> consequences.

I will chalk this up to [unintended consequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLvrU.png)

Environment:

> Windows10 w/ .NET6 installed, VisualStudio 2019, .NET Core 3.1, C# solution/project